# Pig: could not instantiate 'PigStorage' with arguments '[,]'

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to load a simple 4 columned text file into pig, and its just not loading.
The file content is:

```
iphone5s,Apple iPhone 5s,smartphone,24000
iphone6s,Apple iPhone 6s,highendphone,60000
iphone6s_plus,Apple iPhone 6s Plus,highendphone,65000
len_ideapad,Lenovo Ideapad Laptop,laptop,19990
len_yoga,Lenovo Yoga Laptop,laptop,45599
len_ultra_thin,Lenovo Ultra thin Laptop,laptop,18999
len_k900,Lenovo K900,smartphone,14000
len_note3,Lenovo Vibe Note 3,smartphone,10800
len_note4,Lenovo Vibe K4 Note,smartphone,12999
nokia_3310,Nokia 3310 mobile phone,mobilephone,800
nokia_asha,Nokia Asha mobile phone,mobilephone,2499
```

I tried to

```
REGISTER '/usr/hdp/current/pig-client/lib/piggybank.jar';
A = LOAD '/hdfs/path/to/file.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
```

And it keeps cursing me with the error:

```
2017-02-10 14:59:26,398 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse:
<line 1, column 4> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'PigStorage' with arguments '[,]'
```

I tried with `PigStorage()`, `PigStorage(' ')`, `PigStorage('')` but nothing works.
I am using pig version 0.15
I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Where is pig.jar located?

Comment: its located at the place which I have used in REGISTER command.

Comment: I have used PigStorage with "," as a delimiter but did not REGISTER piggybank.jar. Do you really need it ?

Comment: You do not need piggybank.jar.Try executing your script from the location where pig.jar is located.Or else register pig.jar like you have done for piggybank.jar.

Comment: i cannot find pig.jar anywhere. I am using HDP 2.4, and i found piggybank.jar at this location: /usr/hdp/2.4.3.2-1/pig/lib But i see no pig.jar

Comment: i guess there is some issue with pig installation. i ran the same thing in Prod env., its running fine, but in Dev env. its creating a problem. guess need to check with the admins.